# How to determine the space and time complexity of this function

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

I'm trying to determine the space and time complexity of a function I've written so that I can discuss the function in terms of asymptotic bounds in my report.

Given a list of lists, where each sublist represents two elements in "conflict", this function returns a dictionary of **unique** pairwise conflicts. In this context `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` are duplicates of each other so the list `[[1,2], [1,2], [2,1], [3,4]]` would result in the dictionary `{1: [2], 3: [4]}`

```
def calculateDistinctConflicts():
    conflicts = [[1,2], [1,2], [2,1], [3,4]]
    distinctConflicts = {}

    for pair in conflicts:
        element0 = pair[0]
        element1 = pair[1]

        conflictKeys = distinctConflicts.keys()

        if element0 not in conflictKeys and element1 not in conflictKeys:
            distinctConflicts[element0] = []
            targetList = distinctConflicts[element0]
            targetList.append(element1)

        elif element0 in conflictKeys and element1 not in distinctConflicts[element0]:
            targetList = distinctConflicts[element0]
            targetList.append(element1)
        elif element1 in conflictKeys and element0 not in distinctConflicts[element1]:
            targetList = distinctConflicts[element1]
            targetList.append(element0)

        elif element0 in conflictKeys and element1 in distinctConflicts[element0] or element1 in conflictKeys and element0 in distinctConflicts[element1]:
            continue

    print (distinctConflicts)
    # {1: [2], 3: [4]}
```

Comment: You could just use `set([frozenset(pair) for pair in conflicts])`.  That one line would do everything the posted code does, producing a set of frozen sets.  It would also be a lot more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @TomKarzes , the one-liner you provided did indeed produce the same result! I'd love to know the space and time complexity of the function I wrote **as well as** the one-liner you provided. Can you comment on this?

Comment: The one-liner I gave should run in time O(n) where n is the number of elements in the top-level list.  Your version is O(n\*\*2) since you're doing linear searches in the target lists to check for membership, and these can potentially grow to as large as the list length.  Consider your worst case, which is [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], ...].  That's an O(n\*\*2) search.  The version I gave avoids the problem since it relies solely on hash tables.  If you replaced the lists with sets in your version, then it would be O(n) as well.

Comment: I should point out that the O(n\*\*2) time complexity for your version is for the worst-case.  In practice, it's really a matter of how many *different* paired values a given value is likely to have.

Comment: Also note that your version has a bug in it.  If you try it with `[[1,2], [2,3], [2,1], [3,4]]`, you get `{1: [2], 2: [3, 1], 3: [4]}`.  Note that `1:2` and `2:1` both appear.  That's because the `[2,3]` pair causes an entry with key 2, and then when it sees `[2,1]`, it sees that 2 is already a key and just checks its list to see if 1 is present, without first seeing if 1 is also a key.  So there's some missing logic in your version.

Comment: Thanks @TomKarzes ! I will look into the bug as well as using sets. So if the time complexity of the solutions are O(n) and O(n^2) is that also the space complexity for the solutions?

Comment: The space complexity is O(n).  But you really should use the one-line solution I showed, it's clearer, faster, provides a more symmetrical result, and (as you've seen) is less prone to bugs.  If you really one to make your solution work, I suggest the following simplification:  Rather than choosing the dict key based on which value you encounter first, instead always use the smaller of the two values.  I.e., if `element0 > element1` then swap them.  Then you only need to look for `element0` as your dict key, since the values associated with a key will always be >= the key itself.

Comment: @TomKarzes The code is being used for a broader discussion on space and time complexity so I was going to include both pieces of code (along with the URL to this thread and credit to you for your solution) and highlight the differences in complexity between the solutions! Just so I understand, my solution has time and space complexity of O(n^2) and O(n) respectively and your solution is O(n) for both time and space complexity?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Both solutions have space complexity O(n).  The worst-case time complexity of your version is O(n**2) (although the average-case time complexity is probably better, depending on what your data looks like).  My version always has time complexity O(n).

Comment: Oh, I just realized my solution can be simplified to `set(frozenset(pair) for pair in conflicts)`.  I.e., you can remove the square brackets `[` and `]`.  This has the same time and space complexity as before, but avoids creating an intermediate list when constructing the top-level set.